# Reverting from Nvidia back to Nouveau on Debian

Tags: debian, nvidia, graphics, intel-graphics

I installed Nvidia drivers, but something went wrong, and I ended up with a console. I don't really want to waste my and your time with it right now. So I tried to revert the changes. I uninstalled `nvidia-driver` and `nvidia-settings` and ran `Xorg -configure`. There was also some error. But the final result is, now the X and KDE are running. What I don't know is why it happened and how to fix it, here is the error screenshot:

[image]

I am without effects, HW acceleration, and possibly other things.

The integrated graphics card is as follows:

`lspci | grep VGA` output:

```
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
```

- XRender works, OpenGL does not
- `lsmod` output: http://pastebin.com/RuG5vJuy
- `xorg.conf` file: http://pastebin.com/2SkLeSkS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the `nouveau` module is not actually currently loaded. This is likely because the `nvidia` installer blacklisted it to avoid conflicts, then neglected to undo this when it was uninstalled.

Look in `/etc/modprobe.d`; there should be one or more files. One of them may well contain a line with

```
blacklist nouveau
```

or similar. Edit that file to remove the line, then try rebooting.